# Dialogflow CX - Intent not matching

Tags: dialogflow-cx

[page with intent and static fulfillment response, sys.no-match has also static respone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQNsR.png)

[training phrases for intents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBFrF.png)

Using one of the training phrase triggers sys.no-match instead of the intent.
How do I get it to match the intent correctly?

**edit: I ended up changed back from advanced NLU to standard NLU and now it works fine. I initially changed to advanced NLU because I thought it was better but turns out I was wrong**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the Standard NLU is automatically trained after any intent changes, however, switching to the Advanced NLU disables automatic training and the flow needs to be actively trained via the ‘Train’ button in the ML settings. Note that Auto Train is not available for the [Advanced NLU setting](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/agent#settings-ml).

In your situation, despite the intent creation, the training may have not been updated afterwards due to the Advanced NLU setting not automatically doing the training, resulting in the non-updated behavior.

[image: The ML Settings]

In short: to properly use the Advanced NLU setting, you must press the ‘Train’ button before testing and wait for the training status to end ‘Training in progress’ so that the behavior of your Agent reflects the changes made since the last training session.